# How to use lodash filter and map in one string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have code which use 2 lodash method filter and map

```
 const filtered_holidays = filter(holidays, day => day.holiday === 1);
 const type_calendar_holidays = map(filtered_holidays, 'day');
```

How to rewrite this in 1 string in lodash? Some thing like this

```
holidays.filter().map()....

 const filtered_holidays = filter(holidays, day => day.holiday === 1);
 const type_calendar_holidays = map(filtered_holidays, 'day');
```

Comment: I wouldnt use lodash for something so simple native map() and filter() are fine. In JS when you chain something its result gets passed onto the next operation. const filteredHolidays = holidays.filter( day => day.holiday === 1).map(  holiday => holiday.day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap filter with map:

```
 const result = map(filter(holidays, day => day.holiday === 1),'day');
```

You can use [sequence](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#lodash) (requires importing the entire lodash packacge):

```
 const result = _(holidays).filter(day => day.holiday === 1).map('day').value();
```

You can use [`_.flow()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flow) (or [`_.flowRight()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flowRight) aka compose) with [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```
 const result = flow(filter(day => day.holiday === 1), map('day'))(holidays)
```

Note: flow and flowRight are usable in regular lodash as well, but since the order of parameters is backwards, and the function are not auto-curried, you'll need to use [`_.partialRight()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#partialRight).

```
 const result = flow(partialRight(filter, day => day.holiday === 1), partialRight(map, 'day'))(holidays)
```

The easiest solution in this case is to use vanilla js chaining:

```
const result= holidays.filter(day => day.holiday === 1).map(o => o.day);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the filter inside?

```
const type_calendar_holidays = map(filter(holidays, day => day.holiday === 1), 'day');
```

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS, you could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this:

```
holidays.reduce((r, { day, holiday }) => holiday === 1 ? r.concat(day) : r, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just nest the `filter`:

```
const type_calendar_holidays = map(filter(holidays, ({ holiday }) => holiday == 1), 'day');
```